# Как записать данные в БД с добавлением "-"?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

У меня есть .txt файл в котором можество строк в таком формате `Mail:Pass`

Как записать такие данные в базу я знаю:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("D:\\Codding\\Work\\Python\Works\\Bot for searching\\Ready work\\base.bd")
curs = con.cursor()
blb = open(Ab, 'r', encoding='utf-8')

file_data = [re.sub('[()]', '', i).strip('\n').split(';') for i in blb]

print(file_data)
curs.executemany('INSERT INTO dann_PS VALUES (?, ?, ?)', ( file_data) )
con.commit()
```

Мне надо чтобы все время записывать ещё в определенный первый столбец прочерк, вот так "-".

Вот так не работает:

```
curs.executemany('INSERT INTO dann_PS VALUES (?, ?, ?)', ( "-" file_data) )
```

Как реализовать, если у меня в .txt файле данные в `Mail:Pass`, а в базу записывалось `-:Mail:Pass`?

Comment: `... VALUES (?, ?, ?)', ('-', file_data[1:]) )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по описанию в вопросе вы хотите прочитать CSV файл, добавить к данным один столбец (с минусом в качестве данных) и записать все строки в SQLite файл.

Если воспользоваться [модулем Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html), то все решение уложится в несколько строк:

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

con = sqlite3.connect("D:\\Codding\\Work\\Python\Works\\Bot for searching\\Ready work\\base.bd")

# parse CSV to DataFrame
df.read_csv(Ab, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
# insert a new column: "my_new_column_name"
df.insert(0, "my_new_column_name", "-")
# write DataFrame to SQLite table
df.to_sql("dann_PS", con, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

Comment: sqlite3.OperationalError: table dann_MP has no column named fhdhdhs 
Вот такая ошибка (fhfhhf - это строка в csv файле)

Comment: @Vlad, ну в сообщении об ошибке вроде бы все предельно понятно - разве нет?

Comment: Спасибо, все понял!

Comment: А если мне надо прочитать txt файл?

Comment: @Vlad, это зависит от формата TXT файла... Советую открыть новый вопрос с воспроизводимым примером данных

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256292/Запись-данные-в-sqlite3-python-с-добавление-в-txt