# Запись данные в sqlite3 python с добавление “-” в txt

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite3, txt

столкнулся с проблемой при записи в базу sqlite3. У меня есть txt файл в котором множество строк в таком формате Mail:Pass

```
Как записать такие данные в базу я знаю.
con = sqlite3.connect("D:\\Codding\\Work\\Python\Works\\Bot for searching\\Ready work\\base.bd")
curs = con.cursor()
blb = open(Ab, 'r', encoding='utf-8')

file_data = [re.sub('[()]', '', i).strip('\n').split(';') for i in blb]

print(file_data)
curs.executemany('INSERT INTO dann_PS VALUES (?, ?, ?)', ( file_data) )
con.commit()
```

Также знаю как сделать запись с  csv

```
df.read_csv(Ab, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
# insert a new column: "my_new_column_name"
df.insert(0, "my_new_column_name", "-")
# write DataFrame to SQLite table
df.to_sql("dann_PS", con, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

Мне надо что бы все время записывать ещё в определенный первый столбец прочерк вот так "-". Вот так не работает curs.executemany('INSERT INTO dann_PS VALUES (?, ?, ?)', ( "-" file_data) )

В sqlite3 таблице 3 столбца Phone, Mail, Pass

Например в txt 2 столбца:

```
mypocta@gamil.com:pasoow
sjsjsj:18918289
```

Как реализовать если у меня в txt файле данные в Mail:Pass, а в базу записывалось:

```
 -:Mail:Pass ??
```

Comment: Еще в вопросе не хватает структуры таблицы `dann_PS` - можете привести в вопросе SQL скрипт для создания этой таблицы: `create table dann_PS (...)`?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос
 sqlite3 таблице 3 столбца Phone, Mail, Pass

Например в txt 2 столбца mypocta@gamil.com:pasoow sjsjsj:18918289

Comment: а где SQL или структура для таблицы?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю вопрос, таблица состоит из 3 столбцов Phone, Mail, Pass

Comment: а названия столбцов в файле соответствуют наименованиям столбцов в таблице? В файле вообще есть названия столбцов?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
df = pd.read_csv(Ab, sep=':', encoding='utf-8', header=None, names=['mail','pass'])
# insert a new column: "phone"
df.insert(0, "phone", "-")
# append data from the DataFrame to SQLite table
df.to_sql("dann_PS", con, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

Comment: Если pd.read_csv в txt ничего страшного?

Comment: @Vlad, судя по вашему примеру - это CSV файл с расширением `.txt` - если это так, то код в ответе должен отработать правильно